# Partitioning problem

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

OK so FIRST I HAVE NO PRIOR LINUX experience but I am a power user and not afraid of complexity do explain me clearly.

I created a 50 GB partition (Unallocated) then installed Ubuntu 12.04 beta 2 LTS and while installing I choose first option which says install Ubuntu over windows 7 but after installing I got confused that did it get installed on unallocated space as it never asked me about creating partition, but after watching disk management in windows and after trying many partition software I came up with THESE THINGS so please tell me what actually happened and how everything is installed on which drive.

Is my created partition being used or wasted?  Should I merge any partition or leave it as it is?

SITE DOES NOT ALLOWS ME TO POST IMAGES BUT I WILL TELL YOU GUYS WHAT IT SAYS:

1. The extra partition of 51GB that I have created is I think split in 2 drives First one is shown as Ext4 (44.6 GB) (In mini partition tool windows) and second one is shown as Linux Swap (5.9 GB)
2. In windows disk management they both are shown as "Healthy (Primary partition)"

SO PLEASE EXPLAIN ME HOW THINGS ARE INSTALLED AND IS IT BAD.

Comment: Post the images online, let me know, and I'll post them for you

Comment: This site allows to post images !

Comment: @PranitBauva Yes, with the `[!Image description](url)` syntax

Answer (score 3):

I think it is working as you wanted it to.

The two Linux Partitions (Linux SWAP and ext4) have appeared as they should. The ext4 is the actual Ubuntu Partition while the SWAP is a sort of extra RAM that Ubuntu uses (it's equivalent to Windows PAGEFILE.SYS file)

If GRUB has been properly installed then you should be able to select between Linux and Windows in the boot menu.

Comment: Thanks alot and yes Ubuntu boot menu i am able to access Windows i only needed to clear my Doubts thanks alot for your explanation :)

Comment: Glad to help! Just remember to mark the question as solved!